# How frequently can I refresh my access token?

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I am working on an application that requires REST API access via oauth to a large number of salesforce orgs. I need to refresh the access tokens on a timer rather than the traditional `access token -> 4xx -> refresh` flow. How often am I allowed to refresh the token? I ask because I am getting a large number of `invalid_grant` errors on refresh token calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a limit of 3,600 logins per user per hour, so setting a timer of even one second should suffice. Keep in mind that if you have multiple apps logging in, the value is cumulative across all logins. Realistically, you should wait at least 10 minutes between refreshes, because it's not possible for sessions to expire sooner than 15 minutes (other than being manually expired/logged out). I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it might be a better idea to just perform a GetServerTimestamp call every 10 minutes instead of trying to get a new access token; as long as you're *using* the token, it will not normally expire.

Comment: thanks for the info, that is good to know. I am currently only refreshing the token once per hour, but I am still getting a large number of refresh failures. It is odd because the token refresh will fail with `invalid_grant expired access/refresh token` when I try to refresh, but then later on the refresh is successful without requiring reauthentication.